# Databricks delta live table throws error saying, "can't use generated columns"

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables, databricks-unity-catalog

I am using delta live tables for learning.

So, I created tables that look like this:

```sql
/* Silver Layer */

CREATE LIVE TABLE SSliverLive
(
  RowID         INT             COMMENT 'Primary key',  
  OrderDate     DATE,
  ShipDate      DATE,
  OrderYear     INT             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR (OrderDate)),
  ShipYear      INT             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR (ShipDate)),
)
USING DELTA
AS
SELECT *
FROM live.SBronzeLive;
```

```sql
/* Gold Layer */

CREATE LIVE TABLE SGoldLive
AS
SELECT rowid
       , OrderYear
       , COUNT(RowId) AS tt
FROM live.SSliverLive
GROUP BY rowid, orderyear;
```

But, the DLT pipelines throw the below error:

> A generated column cannot use a non-existent column or another generated column.

I followed the SQLBits tutorial online and they can use the generated columns.

Removing the columns works fine but the Databricks website says I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that generated column values are automatically generated based on a user-specified function over other columns in the Delta table.

In your gold table, you mention only `OrderYear`, which is evaluated as `YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear`, but you don't have `OrderDate` defined in the gold table, so it raises an error.

You can use `OrderYear` only when you include `OrderDate` in the SELECT statement, as shown below:

```sql
CREATE LIVE TABLE SGoldLive
 AS 
SELECT
OrderYear,
OrderDate
FROM live.SSliverLive
```

If you include `OrderDate` in the SELECT statement, you will need to add it to the GROUP BY clause, which may not produce the desired results.

Therefore, you should perform a GROUP BY on `OrderYear` without selecting it.

Here's an example using `MONTH`:

Silver table:

```sql
CREATE LIVE TABLE SSliverLive
(
  RowID         LONG             COMMENT 'Primary key',  
  OrderDate     DATE,
  orderMonth    INT              GENERATED ALWAYS AS (month(OrderDate))
)
USING DELTA
AS
SELECT
o_orderkey as RowID,
o_orderdate as OrderDate
FROM LIVE.SBronzeLive
```

Gold table:

```sql
CREATE LIVE TABLE SGoldLive
 AS 
SELECT
COUNT(RowId) AS tt
FROM live.SSliverLive
group by orderMonth
```

This produces output with a single column.

Alternatively, you can use the original column:

```sql
CREATE LIVE TABLE SGoldLive
 AS 
SELECT 
month(OrderDate) as ordMonth,
COUNT(RowId) AS tt
FROM live.SSliverLive
group by month(OrderDate)
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can do this as well. Additionally, if I create tables from views it allows it but not directly which is good but then whats the point of this feature if I cant use it?

Comment: To define partition using generated columns while creating the table. check this once 
https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/generated-columns.html#create-a-table-with-generated-columns

Comment: Thanks @jayashankarGS I have already referred this but the error happens only when I try to create tables as above

Comment: Yes. When creating the table Itself it is used for defining partition based on generated columns.

Comment: I also given how it is evaluated when selecting the generated column.

Comment: Yes, I got that but I am unable to grasp the concept of generated columns, if I cant store it after transforming my data, then whats the use of this functionality? Also adding views on top of generated columns allows me to create a table.

Comment: Even i am checking for that. It might be the issue because of streaming tables i guess.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-streaming-table#limitations